# Single expression in ternary operator in Java

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I know you can have

```
String answer = (5 == 5) ? "yes" : "no";
```

Is it somehow possible to have only:

```
String answer = (5 == 5) ? "yes";
```

It gives a compile error when I try.

NOTE: `(5==5)` is just an example. In its place will be statement which could be either true or false.

Comment: I think a related question (imagining the condition is false) is whether you can write a statement like `String answer = ;` and what that would mean. Alternatively, if the condition *is* always true, you can write `String answer = "yes";`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if one line is important

```
String answer = (5 == 5) ? "yes": null;
```

Since a String's default value is null.

Comment: Or you can also do `answer = (5 == 5) ? "yes" : answer;` if `answer` has been initialized.

Comment: I was doing that before, but I was trying to do it without the ":null". thanks anyway.

Comment: Null cannot be avoided! JK. Any reason though?

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory Not much really :) Just to make it shorter and neater. I could also use : ""; Looks like the second part of the teernary operator is compulsory.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for an `if` statement:

```
if (5 == 5)
    answer = "yes";
```

Your idea is impossible because an expression (such as the conditional value) must **always** have a value.
In your code, if `5 != 5`, the expression would have no value, which wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: This isn't exactly functionally equivalent to what he is asking.

Comment: @Slaks From one line we went to three lines, or FIVE if you include the curly brackets. Don't forget the **String** answer which needs to go in a seperate line. tyvm

Comment: @David: You can't assign nothing to a variable.

Comment: @David The number of lines isn't particularly important. Sometimes it's preferable to have a more verbose version of the code if that's clearer. Remember, source code is for human eyes only. If you have something that's hard for humans to understand, you've beat the purpose of human-readable source code. Might as well code in assembly then.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ It's for academic purposes. In the real world I would agree with you. In this case, I don't. One of the requirements was to keep it as short as possible. If using ternary operators can help me make it even shorter, that's just fine.

Answer (score 4):

No. you can't have it. You need to specify both the ? and :.

Use a straight if.